# digital display

Tags: circuit-design, sensor, design, temperature, non-linear

I was working on a design question (this is not homework, just personal practice).

So I have a temperature sensor with a non-linear response, and ideally I would like to design a digital display system with the following requirements

[image]

Can someone please help me get started or guide me through any worked steps please? Before I create the display I would really appreciate any help I can get with the schematic, thank you and I apologize for any missing tags.

Comment: @periblepsis would love your input on this design, if you have some time

Comment: It sounds to me that you want help with _everything_ here? That's way too broad.

Comment: @pipe doesn't it allow more flexibility with a broader scope though?

Comment: @pipe not really everything, I just want to get started with the circuit, maybe a hint about the implementation, I just need to use a 7 bit A/D converter, 2 switches, opamps and resistors

Comment: It's a breeze to do this with a small microcontroller. To do it with analog electronics sounds needlessly complex (but then I'm a SW guy so I always go with SW over HW).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is convert the bent line into a straight line.

You are given two switches, use one of them to steepen the curve when the voltage hits the first corner, use the other to return it to the correct slope at the second corner.

This will probably involve messing with the feedback path around the op-amp.
using the electronic switches and resistors to different voltages and circuit nodes.

Comment: thank you for the response, can you clarify what bent line you are referring to please?

Comment: bent line on the graph

Comment: so closed switch at the first corner and open switch at the second corner?

Comment: something like that. you need 8 times more gain in the middle section so that section must be with both switches open, and the switches must be arranged to reduce the gain,

Comment: why do I need 8 times more gain in the middle section?

Comment: becase the ends are 1:2  slope and the middle is 4:1  -- oops actually 3:1 in the middle so gain 6 needed

Comment: after the gains and comparators are implemented would the curve look like a digital pulse?

Comment: the plan is to make a straight line that the DAC+Display  can convert to evenly spaced numbers.

Comment: sorry last question, why is the middle line considered a bent line and both the other lines are fine, aren't they all linear?

Comment: I see one line with 2 bends in it,  the DAC wants a line with no bends

Comment: got it thank you!